# How to convert a dataset into an alternative format

Tags: code-request, data-structures

I have the following dataset:

```
rawdata = {{"time", "region", "subregion", "status", "country", 
    "indicator", "data"}, {2000.`, "Africa", "Central Africa", "LDC", 
    "Angola", "Remittances", 0.0267993914860461`}, {2000.`, "Africa", 
    "Central Africa", "LDC", "Angola", "ODA", 
    4.05719895987582`}, {2000.`, "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", 
    "Bhutan", "Tax revenues", 12.9794732034214`}, {2000.`, "Asia", 
    "South Asia", "ODC", "Bhutan", "Gross domestic savings", 
    27.3167848363906`}, {2000.`, "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", 
    "Bhutan", "Adjusted net savings", 44.1909199162357`}, {2000.`, 
    "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", "Solomon Islands", 
    "Gross domestic savings", 0.221702694892883`}, {2000.`, "Asia", 
    "SIDS", "LDC", "Kiribati", "Adjusted net savings", 7.9`}, {2001.`,
     "Africa", "Central Africa", "LDC", "Angola", "Remittances", 
    0.0212549938881954`}, {2001.`, "Africa", "Central Africa", "LDC", 
    "Angola", "ODA", 3.83358753594609`}, {2001.`, "Asia", 
    "South Asia", "ODC", "Bhutan", "Tax revenues", 
    12.5415621434496`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", 
    "Bhutan", "Gross domestic savings", 37.1804901737896`}, {2001.`, 
    "Asia", "South Asia", "ODC", "Bhutan", "Broadband subscriptions", 
    0.497992844`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", "Solomon Islands", 
    "Tax revenues", 4.7808499936`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", 
    "Solomon Islands", "Gross domestic savings", 
    0.38613349199295`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", "Kiribati", 
    "Gross domestic savings", 7.9`}, {2001.`, "Asia", "SIDS", "LDC", 
    "Kiribati", "Internet users", 8.6`}};
```

This `Code`:

```
jdata = Join @@ 
  Map[a \[Function] 
     Dataset[AssociationThread[First@a, #] & /@ Rest[a]]][{rawdata}]
```

generates the following dataset:

[image]

I like to format it in the following structure:

[image]

Note that the final form of the dataset should include all the variables in the `indicator` column of the original dataset. Empty cells in the final form should then be filled by `Missing[]`.

I like to have a MMA function `jdataRev[...]:=` that accepts the original dataset `jdata` as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reOrg = Query[GroupBy[{#"time", #"country"} &] /* Values /* KeyUnion, 
    Apply[Join], 
    <|KeyDrop[{"indicator", "data"}]@#, #indicator -> #data|> &];

ds = reOrg @ jdata
```

[image]

```
ds[All, KeyDrop[{"region", "subregion", "status"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works just the way I imagined. For inserting `Missing[]` into empty cells in the database, I tried `ds[All, KeyDrop[{"region", "subregion", "status"}], 
 "MissingDataRules" -> {(_) -> Missing[]}]` but it did not work. Can you show me how to correctly use the `MissingDataRules` in this context?

Comment: Does MMA automatically treat the cells with `--` or `..` as Missing observation? I see that the format you created does not care about missing observations. When we take the mean of an indicator, for example, it correctly gives me the answer by simply taking the average of the existing data. However, sometimes the mean of an indicator is supposed to consider the missing observations also.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, `"MissingDataRules" ` is an option for `SemanticImport`, not for `Query`. For `Query`, you can use [`MissingBehavior`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingBehavior.html). But in this case, the  function `KeyUnion`  in the first operator  injects `Missing["KeyAbsent", key]` for keys that don't exist. Compare `Normal @ds` with `reOrg2 = Query[GroupBy[{#"time", #"country"} &] /* Values, 
   Apply[Join], <|
     KeyDrop[{"indicator", "data"}]@#, #indicator -> #data|> &];
ds2 = reOrg2@jdata;
Normal@ds2`

Comment: I did compare them. Just to make sure, you mean that I do not have to worry about missing data issues in the current case.